# Using Date Difference to return value with datetime in an sqlserver from today to 7 days ago

Tags: c#, datediff

Basically I am doing a project where i connect to sql and i have to return only values which have null from two columns(tablein and tableout).  I need to do that when this program is run it checks today's date and goes back 7 days and checks from these 7 past days if there is a null value.  It checks from the column tabledate. For now i managed to connect to database and display null values but I am displaying the whole list which has null values.  Now i  tried using date difference to go back 7 days from Today by putting an Sql command as you will see in the code below.  This didn't work and I've been looking through the internet but nothing about what i need is coming up and i was hoping if anyone knew if they could help me with this.  Much appreciated. code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sql_connection
{
class Program
   {
static void Main(string[]args)
{

     DateTime oldDate= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
     DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;

     TimeSpan ts= newDate-oldDate;
     int diffferenceInDays = ts.Days;

    string conn=null;
    SqlConnection connection;
    conn=("Data Source=Database\\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=Table;User ID=user;Password=example");

    connection=new SqlConnection(conn);

    try{

        connection.Open();
        Console.Writeline("Connection Open!");
        SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT tabledate, tablein,tableout,tableuser FROM [dbo].[tb_Showingnull]"WHERE DATEADD(dd,-7,GETDATE()) FROM tabledate AND tablein AND tableout IS NULL);
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{2}, {1} , {0}", reader["tablein"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["tablein"].ToString(), reader["tableout"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["tableout"].ToString(), reader["tableuser"].ToString(), reader["tabledate"].ToString();

        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What didn't work? I don't see where you use `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: You already asked this question [C# checking values from 2 coloums from sql if they have null, within 5 past working days except weekend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077655/c-sharp-checking-values-from-2-coloums-from-sql-if-they-have-null-within-5-past)

Comment: @TimSchmelter in the sql command after where i put tabledate is differenceinDays.

Comment: Looking through your questions I can tell its Stack Overflow Driven Development (SODD) - you put zero efforts by yourself, just keep asking new questions when you get answer to previous

Comment: Your rules are not clear. What does this mean: `WHERE tabledate is differenceinDays tablein AND tableout IS NULL`

Comment: Typo -- `diffferenceInDays` and `differenceinDays`

Comment: Is the column 'tabledate' a datetime column or int?

Comment: @sr28 the column is datetime

Comment: @TimSchmelter i improved the coding

Comment: Just seen your update after posting my answer. Are you now saying that 'tabledate' is a table not just a column in 'tb_ShowingNull'?

Comment: nono its still a column just i named the column tabledate

Comment: What error / issue did you get?

Answer (score 0):

You SqlCommand query looks wrong. The WHERE clause seems to be missing out of the double quotes. I think it should look something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT tabledate, tablein,tableout,tableuser FROM [dbo].[tb_Showingnull] WHERE tabledate = DateAdd(DD," + differenceinDays + ",GETDATE()) AND tablein IS NULL AND tableout IS NULL");
```

You should also note that you need to specify whether 'tablein' should be NULL as well. Writing 'tablein AND tableout IS NULL' won't work to filter on both of them being null. It needs to be 'tablein IS NULL AND tableout IS NULL'.

Comment: incorrect syntax near '>' which is funny because i didn't put that in my coding.

Comment: @bobby - there's no '>' character in that code. You sure you've not put one in somehow? Try your query in SSMS and see if it works.